# Radio button selection dynamically change other radio button value

Tags: javascript, radio-button

So I've tried looking, and I haven't found anything so hopefully this isn't a repeat question.  I have several sets of radio buttons, and I need to have the values associated with the latter radio buttons change dynamically based on the users selection within the first set of radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="length" id="6feet" value=" " >  6'0" 
<input type="radio" name="length" id="6.5feet" value=" " > 6'6"
<input type="radio" name="length" id="7feet" value=" " > 7'0"


<input type="radio" name="weight" ID="weight3" value="5" />  3 
<input type="radio" name="weight" ID="weight4" value="10" /> 4
<input type="radio" name="weight" ID="weight5" value="15" /> 5

<input type="radio" name="pieces" ID="PieceA" value="10">     2
<input type="radio" name="pieces" ID="PieceB" value="20">     3
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to use onClick or something similar to set it so that when the user selects one of the three "length" radio buttons, they will each assign different values to both the weight and pieces radio buttons as well.  Sorry if the question is unclear at all.

Comment: There are several ways of doing this, but most of here at StackOverflow like to see some attempt made at solving the problem on your own.  Just as a hint to get you started:  Create an object that shows, like a tree, what values should be available for `length` then show what `weight` should be available for each `length`.  Then, for each `weight` show what `pieces` should be available.  If you need to, draw them out as a graph first.  It is from this data that you'd update the screen.

Comment: @UmbraJoe, please select the response that you believe answered your question when you get a chance. If none have done so then please update the question for more specific responses. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A pure javascript solution would look similar to this:

```
document.getElementById("6feet").onclick = (function() {
    document.getElementById("weight3").click();     
});
```

You attach the onclick event to an element (in this case the element with id of 6feet) and once that is clicked it calls the defined function.

Read more about [**`.click()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.click)

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gT4Zj/2/)**

There are also simpler solutions using jQuery, but I wasn't sure if you were able to incorporate it into your code.

Comment: or document.getElementById("weight3").click()

Comment: click() may be more clear to the OP, so I'll change it to that. Thanks

Comment: I know, but I'm so used to using jQuery that I honestly prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand totally your question.. is this what you need?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=length]').click(function () {
        $('input[name=weight]').val(newValue);
        $('input[name=pieces]').val(newValue);        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v659L/) and reassign a real "value" for radiobuttons?